# /bin/sh: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'

Tags: ubuntu, cron, sh

Cron can't run job and send me this email:

title:

```
cd /var/www/www-root/data/www/mysite.com/laravel/ && find ./ -mtime -1 -type f -printf "
```

body:

```
/bin/sh: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'  
/bin/sh: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

I'm using ISPmanager and that's cron job:

```
cd /var/www/www-root/data/www/mysite.com/nuxt/ && find ./ -mtime -1 -type f -printf "%p\n" | while read name ; do zip /var/www/www-root/data/www/mysite.com/laravel/storage/app/backup/nuxt_files.zip $name; done
```

That code works perfect in ssh bash and even if I run that cron job by pressing "run" button in the ISPmanager. I have no idea what is wrong with cron.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`cron` replaces a `%` with a newline before sending the command to the shell. To include a literal `%`, you need to escape it:

```
cd /var/www/www-root/data/www/mysite.com/nuxt/ && 
    find ./ -mtime -1 -type f -printf "\%p\n" |
      while read name ; do 
        zip /var/www/www-root/data/www/mysite.com/laravel/storage/app/backup/nuxt_files.zip $name; done
```

From `man 5 crontab`:

> Percent-signs (%) in the command, unless
>        escaped with backslash (), will be changed into newline characters, and
>        all data after the first % will be sent to the command as standard input.

So you are trying to run the first command (with an unmatched `"`) using `p\n" ...` as its input.